# Tab change listner in android

Tags: android, tabs

I make three tabs.

Language.( Include language Class with language layout)
Activation ( Include Activation Class with activate layout)
Settings ( Include Settings Class with setting layout)

In the settings list if i change the setting to hide the words definition in the language layout.
And than again click on the tab language words translation still there.

I think i have to apply here on tab change listner.

But what should i do in on tab change listner.

that is my TabActivity.

```
 package com.languagetranslate;

import com.languagetranslate.Constants.Constants;
import com.languagetranslate.dao.UserData;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class Screen1 extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        initializeTabs();
    }

    private void initializeTabs() {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WordsClass.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Words").setIndicator("Words")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivateClass.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activitation").setIndicator("Activitation")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings").setIndicator(".\n.\n.")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);


        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                if ( tabId == "Language" ){

                    Constants.TAGS_ENABLE = UserData.getTagSettings(getApplicationContext(),
                            Constants.SETTINGS_FILE);
                    if (Constants.TAGS_ENABLE == true) {
                        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
                        View child = inflate.inflate(R.layout.wordlayout, null);
                            child.findViewById(R.id.availabletags).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            child.findViewById(R.id.tags).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            item.addView(child);
//                      
//                      ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.availabletags))
//                              .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                      ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.tags))
//                              .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can put those in Language's onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (Constants.TAGS_ENABLE == true) {
        // set visibility...
    }
}
```

Comment: When we change the tabs on Resume method is called?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to overide `onResume()` in the language Activity and check for changed settings and if so you can put the logic to to hide translation.

onResume will be called when user input is going to the Activity so,

```
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
if(settings_changed)
//logic here

}
```

You may also want to implement the onPause() method.